# Insert and show data from a SQLite database in Titanium

Tags: database, sqlite, titanium, tableview

I'm trying to insert a name in a SQLite database with an "Add" button below the input text field. Also, I want to show it in the same window into a Tableview.

How can I do that in Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great article in the Titanium docs: [Working with a SQLite Database](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database).

It explains many aspects of working with SQLite. Moreover, there is an assignment at the end. If you are having trouble working it through, there is a link providing you the finished Titanium project. You should find many answers there.